# How I can merge audio and video blob on JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, video

I use [Video.js Record](https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record) for recording video from webcam with sound.

Firefox browser returns a single WebM blob object - and this is OK.
But Chrome browser returns two separate blob objects: one for audio and one for video.

How I can get a single WebM blob object from Chrome browser?
Or how I can merge these two blob objects to a single WebM blob object?

Comment: I just run into the same problem today. Unfortunately i didn't find an answer yet.

Comment: When I send blob object to server, i'am use flag (firefox/chrome) - and this crhome browser - i send 2 blob object and merged with ffmpeg: ffmpeg -i "video/input.webm" -i "video/input-audio.wav" -codec:v libx264 -profile:v high -b:v 500k -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1000k -threads 0 -codec:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -movflags faststart "video/output.mp4"

Comment: as far as i know you cant merge the two. you gotta send both to ffmpeg and it merges it for you

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in blob api https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob

`let newBlob = new Blob(array, options);`

Check out this question [Appending Blob data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970729/appending-blob-data)

https://stackoverflow.com/users/977809/nkron seems to have what a complete example of what you're looking for