# How to use html5 JS to merge multiple piece of blob-data and store it via a DOWNLOAD button?

Tags: javascript, html

JS code construct multiply Blob data, like:

```
var b1 = new Blob([..40M..]);
var b2 = new Blob([..40M..]);
var b3 = new Blob([..40M..]);
```

I want to merge `b1, b2, b3` into a single `120M` data and save it as a file, but the memory is of high cost.

Is there any solution to store it in a efficient way, like:

```
downloadFile.append(b1);
downloadFile.append(b2);
downloadFile.append(b3);
```

Comment: Blobs are "immutable" so you can't change one after making it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending Blob data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970729/appending-blob-data)

Comment: Yes, you are right the questions are same! However, when I receive b1, .., b3, ... b10001, .. bN .. through websocket, I actually want to append each received block data to a target download file, and free the memory of them once they have been written on disk...

Comment: You probably want to lookin to something like [StreamSaver.js](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js) - not a viable solution since it only works on chrome v52

Comment: @Infer-On Appending blob data is not a really viable solution as the blob is kept in memory, What you can do is append chunks to a file in a sandboxed filesystem. But that also only works in Blink